# VK Api загрузка фотографии в альбом "Фотографии со стены сообщества"

Tags: c#, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, vknet

Делаю бота для автоматического постинга записей. Т.к. обычные альбомы могут вместить всего лишь 10к фотографий, а альбом "фотографии со стены ..." как минимум более 65к, то было решено загружать фотографии туда.

Появилось 2 решения задачи :

1 - Загрузка фотографии в отдельный альбом вручную по-многу, а потом уже в альбом "фотографии со стены ..." (легко)

2 - Сразу загружать в альбом "фотографии со стены ..." (сложнее)

Когда я зашел в этот альбом, то увидел, что он имеет id 00. Когда я попытался на этот id переместить фотографию, то вышло исключение "несуществование альбома с таким id".

Как решить эту проблему?

Использую библиотеку VKNET для C#

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле это дефолтный альбом с индентификатором `00`, чтобы загрузить туда фотографию, нужно просто загрузить её на стену через `API` методы, такие как: `photos.getWallUploadServer` и `photos.saveWallPhoto`